# Node.js request-promise jar cookies not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, cookies, request

I'm trying to make two API calls. The first one logs in, the last one performs an authorized operation. Even though the login succeeds, the call for the authorized operation produces a 401 unauthorized error. I think it's because the cookie I received isn't sent back in the last call. I've seen that the cookie **is** stored in `jar` though. I tried with Postman, and it worked well.

Here is my code:

```
const request = require('request-promise');

const jar = request.jar();

const loginOptions = () => ({
    method: 'POST',
    url: 'https://www.some-api.com/login',
    jar,
    headers:
    {
        'content-type': 'application/json'
    },
    body: {
        username: "username",
        password: "password"
    },
    json: true
});

const authorizedOperationOptions = (param) => ({
    method: 'GET',
    url: 'https://www.some-api.com/authorized-operation?param=' + param
    timeout: 1000000,
    jar,
    headers:
    {
        'content-type': 'application/json'
    },
    json: true
});

export default async (date) => {
    await request(loginOptions());
    await request(authorizedOperationOptions("value"));
};
```

I'd like to know what I'm doing wrong, but I'll also accept an alternative way to do so with a different library, with a working example code.

Notice that the service was designed to only support web browsers, so maybe it has something to do with that problem.

For those who are not familiar with `await`, it ensures code blocking until the promise is getting fulfilled, and throws in case of rejection.

Comment: "I think it's because the cookie I received isn't sent back in the last call." -- can you try on a simple mock server? So that it would be clear whether it's a client problem or server problem.

Comment: @shaochuancs I tried with Postman and it worked well

Comment: @shaochuancs  I mean I tryied with Postman to the real server, but I think it's a good evidence, isn't it?

Comment: Can't you check if there's anything stored in `jar` after the first call?

Comment: @robertklep well yes, I just checked now and saw that the cookie is stored in jar

Comment: With Postman, is the second request (sent with cookie data retrieved from the 1st request) successful?

Comment: @shaochuancs yes, it is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the service is defined to only support web browsers, I had to impersonate a web browser. I managed it by adding a User-Agent header:

```
headers:
    {
        'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.6) Gecko/20070725 Firefox/2.0.0.6'
    },
```